# Windows Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 not launching the OS

Tags: emulation, windows-10-mobile

I have Windows 10 Pro installed (Hyper-V activated) and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (with "Universal Windows App Development Tools" and "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" installed) . I can launch succesfully all Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators but if I launch Windows Mobile Emulator 10 that is what happens:

- The Phone Emulator opens properly with the write "Loading...".
- After a while appears the write "OS is starting...".
- Finally (after 5-10 minutes) the write disappear *without* launching the OS, the emulator just stays open with the black screen.

Visual Studio doesn't give any error so I really don't know what is the problem.
I also tried to launch the emulator directly from Hyper-V (right click on the emulator->Connect and then Action->Start) but the window just stays black. It seems I can't load the OS.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here except that I do get a crash on XDE.exe and VS shows these two errors: *Error* DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '2DDADD82-5910-40E6-894F-17EB5CD463EF'.': 
ObjectDisposedException - 0x80131622 and *Error* DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 720p 5 inch 1GB' failed. Device cannot be found.

Comment: If I remember correctly I had those errors with Window Phone 8.1 Emulators, i resolved by: deactivating Hyper-V (then restart computer);
going in the Device Manager and open the Network Adapters, here uninstall everything with the name "Hyper-V..." (just to reactivate Hyper-V without any conflict) and finally enabling Hyper-V. Probably you can try this. The strange thing is that my Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators now works fine while Windows Mobile 10 Emulators are not... Does this happens to you too?

Comment: Did all the said methods. Remove Hyper V, remove networks related, reinstall HyperV, Repair Windows 8.1 emulators, repair Windows 10 emulators, repaired Android emulators. Same result.

Comment: Do you have found a solution?
I meet the same problem...

Comment: No... still testing my app on my computer since Windows Mobile 10 slows to be released

Comment: Yes  Niccolo, On my Win 10 machine, Win Phone 8.1 emulators are working fine while Win Phone 10 emulators are not

Answer (score 0):

Open your HyperV, Open `Visual Switch Manager` .

Find VisualSwitch related to the Emulator ,click on it .

In `Connection Type` ,set connection to `Private network` ,Then press OK and restart your PC .After restart do the same and change `Connection Type` to `Internal network` and then restart.

Then it should work ,I guess!